# MySQL relationships. User roles

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, user-roles

I have 3 type of user roles: Patient, Doctor, Pharmasist

And Tables:

### Users

*id | name | surname | username | password | etc..*

---

### Roles

*id  |  name*

---

1. Patient
2. Doctor
3. Pharmasist

### users_roles

*id  |  user_id  |  role_id*

---

And I want to implement tables such as: doctor_info, patient_info, pharmasist_info.

For example:

### doctor_info

*id | experience | qualification | user_id*

What relationship should I use to tie users with doctor_info, patient_info, pharmasist_info and how to implement it correctly?

Comment: First you ll have to consider 1-to-1, 1-to-many or many-to-many first. Those are depending on the requirement. Then I can help you with constraints.

Comment: i think i need 1-to-1 relationship so 1 user(doctor) can have only 1 doctor_info

Comment: how about `user` and `role`? 1 user 1 role but 1 role many users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all id column from each table is primary key.

**users**:
id, name, ...

**roles**:
id, name

**users_roles**:
id, user_id, role_id (make user_id UNIQUE key, so 1 user can only have 1 role)

**doctor_info**:
id, user_id, ... (make user_id UNIQUE key as well, so 1 user can only be 1 doctor)

**patient_info**:
similar to doctor_info

**pharmasist_info**:
similar to doctor_info

(OPTIONAL) If 1 user has 1 role and 1 role is belonged to many users, you could remove `users_roles` table completely, and just add `role_id` in `users` table.

One issue is that you can have: 1 user can be a doctor, a patient and a pharmasist altogether with your table structure. You'll have to add some validation in your code to make sure it won't happen.